# infix to postfix expressrion not showing any output

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

infix to posfix expresion where a+b is converted in ab+.

i have been staring at the code for hours and wondering why is not showing any output at all. i tried reviewing it by line to the best that i could and still could not figure it out why. can anyone point out where im wrong or is it my code does not make any sense at all. also, i am only allowed to use array and string.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string stack; //initialize stack to contain operators
int top=-1;

void push(char a){  //add/push it to stack
    top++;
    stack[top] = a;
}

char pop(){ //delete/pop the stack
    return stack[top--];
}

int order_operation(char a){ //the precedence priority

    if(a=='+' || a=='-'){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(a=='*' || a=='/'){
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 3;
    }
}

int main(){
    string infix,postfix;

    cout<<"infix: ";
    getline(cin,infix);

    for(int x = 0; x<infix.length(); x++){   //scan the infix for operator
        if(infix[x]=='-' || infix[x]=='+' ||infix[x]=='*' || infix[x]=='/'){
            while(!stack.empty() && order_operation(stack[top])>=order_operation(infix[x])){ //if the stack is not empty and check the precedence

                postfix+=stack[top];  //add it to postfix string
                pop();  //pop the stack operator
            }
            push(infix[x]); 
        }
        else{
            postfix+=infix[x]; //add to postfix string if its operand
        }
    }

    while(!stack.empty()){ //if the stack is not empty put it to posfix string
        postfix+=stack[top];
        pop();
    }
    cout<<postfix;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `cout<<postfix;` to `cout<<postfix<<endl`. It might be getting stuck in the buffer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. it still not showing any output.

Comment: Try `cout << postfix.size() << endl;` (or however you get the size of a string in C++. It's been awhile).

Comment: i also tried cout<<postfix.length() <<endl; and gives me 0. does that mean im not adding anything to postfix string?. thanks

Comment: Ya, your string is empty. It is printing, it's just that printing an empty string doesn't show anything for obvious reasons. I'm assuming EJP's second suggestion fixes that.

Comment: @noobiee *i have been staring at the code for hours* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler and single-step through your program, watching variables, program flow, etc.  Just staring at code isn't the way to solve the problem.

Comment: Or just standard print debugging. Probably could have tracked down the issue using `cout`s in the time it would take to start a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add `endl` as stated by @Carcigenicate.
2. Your `pop()` method is incorrect. It should pop and return the actual value at the top of the stack, and it should not take an argument. At present you are corrupting the stack every time you pop it.

Comment: so pop function should only contains  top-- ?

Comment: No. You missed the part about 'and return'. `return stack[top--];`

Comment: hi, although i manage to show some output. still, im having some difficulties in showing the operators. i implement your suggestion and seems it is not working. i tried it in a small pop program and it was working but, when i implement it here it was not working. sorry for the inconvenience , thanks